# How to delete duplicate values and write to different files?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file that looks like this:

```
    83 124 125
    83 125 126
    83 126 127
    83 127 128
    83 128 128
    154 120 120
    154 120 121
    154 121 122
    154 122 123
    154 123 124
    122 92 93
    122 93 94
    122 94 95
    122 95 96
    122 96 97
```

And write to different files every set of values. The first value (`83` / `154` / `122`) needs to be the text file's name. The rest of the values should be written into their correspondent file like so: `124 128`

So file `"83.txt"` contains `124 128`. The file `"154.txt"` contains `120 124`. And the file `"122.txt` should contain `92 97`.

How do i iterate over the above mentioned input and remove duplicate values from the first column? Then proceed into taking the minimum and maximum values that each of the first values share? and finally write each separate line into a new text file inside a certain folder?

I have tried to use:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def final(f):
    with open (f+'.txt', 'r') as fin:
        lines = fin.readlines().split().strip('\n')
        v1, v2, v3 = lines[0], lines[1], lines[2]
        for v1, g in groupby(enumerate(diffs[v1x]), lambda (i, x): i - x):
            group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
            lines.itertools.chain()
            lines = defaultdict(list)
            print (lines),
```

Which is an incomplete version of what i had earlier but i can't seem to make it work like it did before. Anyway my code ended up very long and not that readable... If more details are required for this to be answered I'll provide them. I'd like to see different takes on this and not simply posting my crude code and get it tweaked by someone.

Comment: It's still "required" to provide your existing code... Anyway - are your filenames always consecutive, or can appear anywhere?

Comment: The filenames order does not matter that much if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the filenames are "in order", and the other items are in order, then:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import deque

with open('/home/jon/testdata.txt') as fin:
    lines = (line.split() for line in fin)
    for k, g in groupby(lines, itemgetter(0)):
        fst = next(g)
        lst = next(iter(deque(g, 1)), fst)
        with open(k + '.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(fst[1] + ' ' + lst[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long_string = """    83 124 125
    83 125 126
    83 126 127
    83 127 128
    83 128 128
    154 120 120
    154 120 121
    154 121 122
    154 122 123
    154 123 124
    122 92 93
    122 93 94
    122 94 95
    122 95 96
    122 96 97
"""

files = {}
for line in long_string.split("\n"):
    try:
        filenum, minvalue, maxvalue = line.strip().split(" ")
        try:
            new_min = min(files[filenum][0], minvalue)
            new_max = max(files[filenum][1], maxvalue)
            files[filenum] = (new_min, new_max)
        except KeyError:
            files[filenum] = (minvalue, maxvalue)
    except ValueError:
        print("There are no 3 values as excpected")

for filename, values in files.iteritems():
    with open(filename + ".txt", "wb") as writer:
        writer.write(values[0] + " " + values[1])
```